# Term for the depressions left by a pen tip on an underlying paper sheet

Tags: vocabulary

Is there a specific term for the depressions / indentations left on an underlying sheet of paper caused by the pressure applied from the tip of a pen or pencil writing on a sheet of paper above it?

(Like something from an Agatha Christie novel...).

Comment: I'm thinking I've seen something like "indentation" or "impression" most of times that I've seen this described,  It was a standard gimmick in old detective stories, but I don't think there was a special term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Impression**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/impression)

- "a mark, indentation, figure, etc., produced by pressure.
- "the act of impressing; state of being impressed"

Answer (score 2):

[Debossing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_embossing) which wikipedia describes as *a debossed pattern is sunken into the surface of the material*.

Or, [indented writing](http://www.questioneddocuments.com/services-offered-by-ndl/indented-writing/) which the Norwich Document Library describes as *indented writing, or second page writing, is the impression from the writing instrument captured on sheets of paper below the one that contains the original writing.*

Answer (score 2):

If it's only a faint copy which has to be carefully studied to be read, you can call it  a **"second page writing"**.  Unlike [carbonless copy paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonless_copy_paper) which uses micro-encapsulated dye, a second-page writing relies only on pressure applied on the front sheet.  There are [a few methods](http://www.questioneddocuments.com/services-offered-by-ndl/indented-writing/) that make the writings clear, and reading a second-page writing, or **"indented writing"** as mentioned in another answer by E. Frisch, is often helpful to police investigators when such pages are found at a crime scene.

At home, we can try to recover second-page writings (or indented writing)

- applying oblique light to the document
- rubbing a soft lead pencil over its surface

[image]

Modern, well-equipped forensic laboratories, however, employ electrostatic detection to recover what was written on the front page.